# Save As - html thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

we need to develop an application similar to the below

On the web page user is asked to select the parameters which are present in a Map<String,Boolean>. Once the user selects his choice of parameters then this Map is saved in a .DAT file. Right now I am saving it in C:/Users/Application. But I want the user to choose which directory he wants to save. I was tempted to use <input type="file".....> but it needs a file in the directory.

Is there any way that the user can specify his own directory where this .DAT file is saved.

Something similar to SaveAs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webpage cannot choose where the user will download a file that is returned. For some file types, the browser might even show the file instead of downloading it (e.g. PDF file).